# How can I add an onmouseout event to a javascript tabs panel

Tags: javascript, onmouseout

i'm currently using this tabs panel (http://www.oaa-accessibility.org/example/35/) for ADA compliance and i need to add an onmouseout to the feature.  I'm pretty horrible at javascript so how would i go about that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var panel1 = new tabpanel("tabpanel1", false);
});
```

i'm sure the answer is pretty simple

Comment: are you using JQuery or any other javascript libraries?

Comment: JQuery 1.11 is being used

Comment: can you add jquery as a tag

Answer (score 0):

This will bind to the tabpanel div and fire anytime u get a mouse out event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var panel1 = new tabpanel("tabpanel1", false);
  $(panel1.$panel).mouseout(function(){
     ## do something
   });
});
```

Comment: This will bind to the tabpanel div and fire anytime u get a mouse  out event

Answer (score 0):

it appears you are using jquery, you can use the `mouseleave` event. so could handle event several ways: `.bind()` (*best*), `.on()` (*better*), or `mouseleave()` (*ok*). See below for examples.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var panel1 = new tabpanel("tablpanel1", false);
    $(tablpane1).bind("mouseleave", function(){
        //code here
    });
});
```

Alternate 1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var panel1 = new tabpanel("tablpanel1", false);
    $(tablpane1).on("mouseleave", function(){
        //code here
    });
});
```

Alternate 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var panel1 = new tabpanel("tablpanel1", false);
    $(tablpane1).mouseleave(function(){
        //code here
    });
});
```